# Mimic Joomla Login via cron

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, joomla, cron

I am trying to login into joomla (front-end) via cron job and i am getting a success but i want to mimic the joomls login 100% same as we do from a browser..
In other words, i need to set all session and cookies stuffs via cron just like we do from browser..

### Here is the small code i am using in cron file.

```
global $_SERVER;
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
$baseFolder = '/var/www/vhosts/pervbook.com/httpdocs';
define('JPATH_BASE', $baseFolder );
define('HTTP_HOST', 'localhost' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
$options = array();
$options['remember'] = true;
$credentials = array();
$credentials['username']='brian';
$credentials['password']='nogdnakw';
$result=$mainframe->login($credentials,$options);

----------------------------------------------
```

I am getting 1 in $result that means login is working without error. But i think sessions and cookies are not being set as we login from a browser.
Can i get some help ?

Comment: It's been a while since I have had to work in Joomla, but I believe sessions are handled in the DB so you would have to establish a session there, but my bigger question is why do you need to log in this way? What are you trying to accomplish? I just finished a project a while back that updates the Joomla DB with an external script from a 3rd party API. We then run this script on a CRON. I think this may be a better path as it can be done independent of the Joomla login.

Comment: Hey Sandra, thank you putting some light on the issue.. The reason i want to login this way is JomSocial..  I have jomsocial running on my website and it has a module called "Community toolbar". when i disable this toolbar, the login works like charm but when i enable community toolbar, the login takes 3-4 minutes to get user in on every 12 hours.  So we decoded to run a cron every 4-5 hours which will login a particular user every 4-5 hours and then if any other user login, it doesn't take so long. We have tested this by login from 2 different countries.